# gnuplot missing data with expression evaluation

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use the `plot` command in gnuplot with expression evaluation, i.e.

```
plot "-" using ($1):($2) with lines
1 10
2 20
3 ?
4 40
5 50
e
```

But I want it to ignore the missing data "?" in such a way that it connects the line (and doesn't break it between 2 and 4).
I tried `set datafile missing "?"`,
but in agreement with the online-help it does not connect the lines. The following would, but I cannot use expression evaluation:

```
plot "-" using 1:2 with lines
1 10
2 20
3 ?
4 40
5 50
e
```

Any ideas how to connect the lines *and* use expression evaluation?

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you want? Are you talking about using math expression minus, or reading from stdin (special filename "-")? Some more real sample data would be helpful.

Comment: The special file "-" is just used in the online-help example. It could be any datafile in gnuplot format for 2-d plots. Just put the two columns in a file named "data.dat" and translate the commands into plot "data.dat" using ($1):($2) with lines, or  "data.dat" using 1:2 with lines. Expression evaluation means that I want e.g. plot "data.dat" using ($1):($2/$1) with lines, which makes sense only if the brackets are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two column data

If you set up a data file `Data.csv`

```
1 10
2 20
3 ?
4 40
5 50
```

you can plot your data with connected lines using

```
plot '<grep -v "?" Data.csv' u ($1):($2) w lp
```

#### More than two column data

For more than two columns you can make use of *awk*.
With a data file *Data.csv*

```
1 10 1
2 20 2
3 ?  3
4 40 ?
5 50 5
```

you can run a script over the data file for each plot like so:

```
plot "<awk '{if($2 != \"?\") print}' Data.csv" u ($1):($2) w lp, \
     "<awk '{if($3 != \"?\") print}' Data.csv" u ($1):($3) w lp
```

A reference on scripting in gnuplot can be found [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile3-e.html). The *awk* user manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: Yes, but this does not work (in the required way) if I have a three column data file, where the third column has correct data in the third line which I do want to use. Admittedly the two-column example given above is too simplistic for that. But if I have just two columns there are of course plenty of ways to remove the unknown data.