# Plot cyclic sum of some row data

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that store for a given timestamp k values.

Ex:

```
# data.dat
# Example for k = 3    
# Time ID value
1  0 1.555
1  1 1.76
1  2 12.56
2  0 1.75
2  1 2.04
2  2 13.04
3  0 2.01
3  1 0.52
3  2 12.99
# ...
```

I can print individually the data of each ID versus the time as follows:

```
set xrange [0:4]
set yrange[0:14]
set xtics 1
plot "data.dat" every 3    using 1:3 title "ID=0" with lp, \
     ""         every 3::1 using 1:3 title "ID=1" with lp, \
     ""         every 3::2 using 1:3 title "ID=2" with lp
```

Yet I'm interested to plot the average sum of the 3 values vs time. 
Of course, I could regenerate a new data file containing (with evaluated sum):

```
# avg_data.dat modified to 
# Example for k = 3    
# Time ID value
1  (1.555+1.76+12.56)/3
2  (1.75+2.04+13.04)/3
3  (2.01+0.52+12.99)/3
# ...
```

But of course, I'm seeking an automated way do express that in gnuplot using the `data.dat` file directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing some inspiration from the [running average demo on the gnuplot site:](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/data_feedback.html)

```
k = 3

back1 = back2 = back3 = 0 

shifter(x) = (back3 = back2, back2 = back1, back1 = x)
avger(x,y) = (shifter(x), y == k - 1 ? (back1 + back2 + back3)/3 : 1/0)

plot 'data.dat' u 1:(avger($3, $2)) with points pt 7
```

This works for me in gnuplot 4.6.1.  If you want to have the points at each timestep connected in a line, it may be better to preprocess the data, since gnuplot in general won't connect points resulting from an expression evaluation (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600048/gnuplot-missing-data-with-expression-evaluation) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/440947/in-gnuplot-how-to-plot-with-lines-but-skip-missing-data-points), and in the gnuplot docs for `set datafile missing`).