# In gnuplot, with "set datafile missing", how to ignore both "nan" and "-nan"?

Tags: gnuplot, nan, missing-data, infinity

The gnuplot command `set datafile missing "nan"` tells gnuplot to ignore `nan` data values in the data file.

How to ignore both `nan` and `-nan`? I tried the following in gnuplot, but then the effect of the first statement is overwritten by the next.

```
gnuplot> set datafile missing "-nan"
gnuplot> set datafile missing "nan"
```

Is it possible to somewhow embed a `grep  -v nan` in the gnuplot command, or even some kind of regexp to exclude any imaginable non-numerical data?

Comment: Refer to this question for using grep with gnuplot commnad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600048/gnuplot-missing-data-with-expression-evaluation

Comment: Upvote for being the #1 pick in Google June 2018

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to use a regexp for `set datafile missing`, but you can use any program to filter you data before plotting, and replacing a regexp with one character, e.g. `?` which you set to mark a missing data point.

Here is an example which accomplishes, what you originally requested: filtering `-nan`, `inf` etc. For testing, I used the following data file:

```
1 0
2 nan
3 -inf
4 2
5 -NaN
6 1
```

And the plotting script may look like the following:

```
filter = 'sed -e "s/-\?\(nan\|inf\)/?/ig"'
set datafile missing "?"
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
plot '< '.filter.' data.txt' with linespoints ps 2 notitle
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

So the plot command skips all missing data points. You can refine the `sed` filter to replace any non-numerical values with `?`, if this variant is not enough.

This works fine, but allows only to select columns e.g. with `using 1:2`, but not doing computations on the columns, like e.g. `using ($1*0.1):2`. To allow this, you can filter out any row, which contains `nan`, `-inf` etc with `grep`, like its done in [gnuplot missing data with expression evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607368/2604213) (thanks @Thiru for the link):

```
filter = 'grep -vi -- "-\?\(nan\|inf\)"'
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
plot '< '.filter.' data.txt' with linespoints ps 2 notitle
```

Comment: This is really good, thanks! Your suggested sed filter only replaces the first match by a "?". It is really fine for my purpose because gnuplot will ignore a line if there is just one "?" in it. It's a bit off-topic question now: How can the filter replace all occurrences of the relevant strings, for example with "inf -nan 2.43" the filtered one should be "? ? 2.43"

Comment: @user1069609 Just add a `g` behind the `i` in the sed pattern. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Upvote for being the #1 pick in Google June 2018, and for allowing me to get this answer in under a minute.  This is a great database because of contributors like yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple *gnuplot-only* solution without using `sed` or `grep`, hence, platform-independent.
You can also do calulations on the columns, e.g. `x0=$1*0.1` or `y0=$2**2`.

There is the gnuplot function `valid()` which checks if a column value is valid (check `help valid`).
This works for `NaN`, `nan`, `-nan`, etc., but strangely `inf`, `+inf` and `-inf` are considered as valid.
So, you have to filter them separately as well.

The simple "trick" making the linespoints plot connected between datapoints, even without `set datafile missing` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599).

**Data:** `SO18718100.dat`

```
1 0
2 nan
3 -inf
4 2
5 -NaN
6 1
7 +inf
8 +NaN
9 1
10 inf
11 0
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### ignore several non-valid data entries
reset

FILE = "SO18718100.dat"
Check(col) = valid(col) && !(s=strcol(col), s[sgn(strstrt('+-',s[1:1]))+1:strlen(s)] eq "inf") 

plot FILE u (Check(2)?(y0=$2,x0=$1):x0):(y0) w lp pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "red"
### end of script
```

The shortest version if you don't have `inf` values in your data would be:

```
plot FILE u (valid(2)?(y0=$2,x0=$1):x0):(y0) w lp
```

**Result:**

[image]