# Completely ignore some lines of data in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, pivot-table

I would like to draw a kind of PivotChart using Gnuplot.
So I need to ignore some lines of data in my file.
I tried the following:

```
unset key

set xtics font "Times-Roman, 5" 
set ytics font "Times-Roman, 5" 

set multiplot layout 4,3 #title "Multiplots\n"

plot [7:50][0:1] 'forStackoverGnuplot.txt' using 1:($2==0?($3==4?$4:NaN):NaN) with lines ti '4'
plot [7:50][0:1] 'forStackoverGnuplot.txt' using 1:($2==0?($3==4?$4:"fe"):"fe") with lines ti '4'
```

Datafile:

```
20  0   5   0.668593155
7   0   4   0.885223087
20  0   5   0.668593155
10  0   4   0.92239289
20  0   5   0.668593155
20  0   4   0.834947746
30  0   4   0.693726036
50  0   4   0.47169919
```

But I get:
[image: Bad charts]

which is not the result I expected. What can I do? I want to let the data lines interlaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, `gnuplot` differentiates between missing and invalid data points, see e.g. [In gnuplot, with “set datafile missing”, how to ignore both “nan” and “-nan”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718574/2604213).

If you have an undefined point (e.g. as `NaN` or `1/0`), the plot line is interrupted. To achieve this, you would need to set `datafile missing`. But that doesn't work if you evaluate something in the `using` statement, because then its too late for the 'undefined' <-> 'missing' choice (Selecting columns e.g. with `using 1:4` is ok). So the statement

```
set datafile missing '?'
plot 'forStackoverGnuplot.txt' using 1:(($2==0 && $3==4) ? $4 : '?')
```

does *not* work.

Instead you must filter the data externally, and remove the affected rows, before plotting them:

```
unset key
set style data linespoints

set multiplot layout 1,2 

plot [7:50][0:1] 'forStackoverGnuplot.txt' using 1:(($2==0 && $3==4) ? $4 : 1/0)

filter = '< awk ''{ if ($2 == 0 && $3 == 4) print $1, $2, $3, $4}'' '
plot [7:50][0:1] filter.' forStackoverGnuplot.txt' using 1:4

unset multiplot
```

This gives:

[image]

In the left graph the points are plotted, but are not connected by lines, because there are 'invalid' points between them.