# specifying points in space associated with a particular value in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have 10x10x10 grid points. Some of these points are associated with a value 1 and the others are associated with a value -1. I want to specify(give a color to) only those points which have value 1. Can anyone please tell me how this can be achieved in Gnuplot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An obvious way to do this is by filtering your data with some utility. If your data structure is `x y z w` where w is either 1 or -1, then you can use `awk` to filter this data to a temporary file which will only display the data points with w=1: `awk '{if ($4 == 1) print $0}' datafile > temp` and then plot it with gnuplot: `splot "temp"`.

Comment: @Miguel If the OP wants only to draw points, the filtering inside of gnuplot is also possible: `splot 'file' using 1:2:($4 == 1 ? $3 : 1/0) with points`.

Comment: Thanks Miguel and Christoph.
@ Christoph: I am a newbie to gnuplot, so can you also please take a little more trouble to explain me what the syntax means. Thanks

Comment: @Christoph: I didn't know about this `1/0` thing, but it seems pretty useful.

Comment: @Miguel That trick works fine as long as you plot points. If you want to filter out some points but connect the others with lines, it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19001406/2604213

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out completely all points with value `-1`, you can do it as follows:

```
splot 'file' using 1:2:($4 == 1 ? $3 : 1/0) with points
```

That assumes, that your data file has four columns with the x, y, z value in the columns 1, 2, 3 and in the fourth column the values `1` or `-1`.

With the `using` statement you can specify which columns are used for plotting: `using 1:2:3` uses the first column as x, the second as y and the third column as z value.

You can also do calculations inside the `using` statement. In that case you must put the respective expression in braces, and refer to the values of a column with e.g. `$3` or `column(3)`: `using 1:2:($3/10)` would scale the values in the third column by `10` and use the result as z value.

The expression I used above, `using 1:2:($4 == 1 ? $3 : 1/0)` does the following: If the value in the fourth column is equal to `1`, use the value in the third column, otherwise use `1/0`. The 'special' value `1/0` makes gnuplot ignore a point.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph, that was immensely helpful.

Comment: @user3527002 Great! If that answer solved your problem you can accept it :)